# how to pass a folder path to mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, path, server.mappath

I am trying to pass a folder path to a download controller using `@Html.ActionLink`, but I am getting could not find the location error like

> Could not find file 'C:\Teerth
>   Content\Project\Colege\WebApp\Media\@item.Content'

However when I give the hard coded value it does work. May I have suggestions what is wrong with that.

Here is my code:
Action method:

```
public FileResult Download(string fileName, string filePath)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    string documentName = fileName;
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, documentName);
}
```

view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "Marketing", routeValues: new
{
    fileName = @item.Content,
    filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Media/@item.Content"), 
    area = "AffiliateAdmin"
}, htmlAttributes: null)
```

Comment: `filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Media/"+@item.Content)`

Comment: Thank you for finding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700678/how-to-pass-a-folder-path-to-mvc-controller#comment47537184_29700678), you've got an error in your view:

The code `("~/Media/@item.Content")` renders as `C:\Teerth Content\Project\Colege\WebApp\Media\@item.Content`, where you actually want `Server.MapPath("~/Media/" + @item.Content)` to find the actual filename.

But you need to reconsider this design, as it opens up your entire machine to the web. Someone is bound to try `Download("C:\Teerth Content\Project\Colege\WebApp\web.config", "web.config")`, exposing your connection strings and other application settings, not to mention other files on your server you really don't want clients to download.